# Facebook Fan Page API: How to call this API call using Facebook graph and PHP API

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, curl

I have tried a lot but no luck. I want to call following API call using graph API like `https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/settings?option={options}&access_token={page token}` and Facebook PHP API.

```
curl -F 'method=post'
     -F 'option={"COUNTRY_RESTRICTIONS" : {"restriction_type":"blacklist", "countries":["PL", "FR"]}}'
     -F 'access_token={page_access_token}'
      https://graph.facebook.com/546349135390552/settings
```

You can find above API call here 
[Facebook Fan Page API Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/managing)

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the Page ID in the API call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/page-id/settings...
```

Anyway, since you edited the question and that´s not the problem, here´s a tutorial about using PHP curl with POST: http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

Another example from Stackoverflow: [PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

Comment: Sorry, actual call has page_id. I edited the question.

Comment: edited my answer, check it out. it´s better to give you a hint so you can solve it on your own and learn something, instead of just posting a finished solution ;)

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code @luschn

Comment: thanx, added to the answer

Comment: Thanks. Already solved it using the same link. Thanks a lot for your reply. @luschn

Answer (score 1):

Complete call for PHP SDK would look like this:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'POST',
  '/page_id/settings',
  array(
    'debug' => 'all',
    'option' => '{"COUNTRY_RESTRICTIONS" : {"restriction_type":"blacklist", "countries":["PL", "FR"]}}'
  )
);

$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. At the moment I can't use PHP. I will be very thankful if your translate it in https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/setting?..... like API call.

Comment: It's a POST request, so you can't use a simple GET URL request. For CURL the requests looks like this:

<code>
curl -i -X POST \
 -d "debug=all" \
 -d "option=%7B%22COUNTRY_RESTRICTIONS%22%20%3A%20%7B%22restriction_type%22%3A%22blacklist%22%2C%20%22countries%22%3A%5B%22PL%22%2C%20%22FR%22%5D%7D%7D" \
 -d "access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/your_page_id/settings"
</code>

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. Can I use simple PHP curl call with page access token to achieve this goal? If yes, please transate it. I can't use Facebook PHP API because I came to know after I post this question.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I solved it. I will use your PHP SDK solution when I need it. @lars.schwarz